# Apple Mach-O Linker Error lxml

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I just upgraded xcode to 4.5 and now i get an error when compiling :

```
ld: library not found for -lxml2.2.7.3
cland: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I did not change my code after the upgrade...
So?

thanks!

Comment: never ever link to a specific version unless you need to. simply link towards libxml2 and not down to the last dot revision.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Click on your projekt ☞ target ☞ build phases ☞ link binary with libraries
then remove `lxml2.2.7.3.dylib` and add `lxml2.dylib` (if your project does not depend on a specific version of that library).

Comment: sir lxml2.2.7.3.dylib it is not show in the >  link binary with libraries?

Answer (score 0):

For my ionic project, I found that opening the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj fixed this issue