# ld: library not found for -lopencv_imgproc error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While building my project, I am getting this error.

ld: library not found for -lopencv_imgproc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What kind of library it is.? Can somebody explain.

Comment: remove all pods from your project and reinstall all pods and make deep clean your project and make build.

Comment: I am not using pods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676885/apple-mach-o-linker-error-lxml

Comment: Are you using opencv framework? it is the open source framework. Which is used to filter the images and facial recognition and other operation performed using this framework

Comment: yes it is in Card Library. But this existing in project, not missing. I cleaned and build, still getting this error.

Comment: Do I need to update my library, as i am using older one?

Comment: Thank you for your advices, and explaining the library, i updated Card IO, and get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend there are a lot of reason of linkers error. Some basic reason: 
1. You can remove linker error goto Build **Setting>Build** Active Architecture Only set to No for Target and Project both.
2. Sometimes unnecessary .a files created **Target>General**. Delete irrelevant .a files.
3. Delete all library paths from  Build **Setting>Search Paths(o top)** which you are not using like AFNetworking then pls delete -lAFNetworking path.

Try this if still you got the error show me the screenshot. 
Thanks

Comment: thanks you, but it got resolved after updating library.